# Using Cauchy's Integral Formula and Theorem with polynomials in $\bar{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Evaluate $\oint_{\partial{D(1+i,2)}} (\bar{z}+1)^2dz $ by making use of Cauchy's Integral Theorem and Formula.

Since this is a homework problem, I just want a hint to get started. The obvious hangup is that $(\bar{z}+1)^2$ is not holomorphic. I've maybe considered that $$\oint_{\partial{D(1+i,2)}} (\bar{z}+1)^2dz =\oint_{\partial{D(-1-i,2)}} ({z}+1)^2dz=0 $$

This does not pair up with my parameterized solution of $16\pi +32\pi i$, nor does it make use of CIF, so I know it is incorrect - but I do not know why. I'm genuinely stumped!

Comment: If only we could decompose $\overline{z}$ into parts, distribute the integral over those parts, change variables in the irritating one, un-distribute the integrals, and see something familiar...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that on that boundary $$\overline{z}=\frac{4}{z-1-i}+1-i.$$